# Not Able To Spin Comments , Python automation ,tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, bots

Basically i am creating a bot for a learning purpose, what i am trying to do is user add commas with comment to spin the comments, but it's not working if user add in comment box like hey, "amazing" "cool", then the bot comments in random words like "h","y","I, basically it's randomizing the first character,

**Here are the codes**

```
def comment(driver, comment_custom,hashtags,count):

url = "https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/"+ hashtags
driver.get(url)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
path = "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[2]"
first_photo = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,path)))
first_photo.click()

time.sleep(1)

next_button1st = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div/button")
next_button1st.click()   
time.sleep(1)


for i in range (int(count)):
    #comments on photo
    path = "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/article/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea"
    comment = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"Ypffh")))
    comment.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    commet_text = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "Ypffh")))
    comment = comment_custom[randint(0, len(comment_custom)-1)]
    commet_text.send_keys(comment)
    
    #post comment button
    post_button = wait.until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(.,'Post')]")))
    post_button.click()
    time.sleep(1)

    next_button2st = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button")))
    next_button2st.click()
```

**and this is the code of tkinter**

```
Comments_with_hash = Button(root, text="Comments_with_hashtags", height=1, width = 30,
command=lambda:comment(driver,comments.get(),hashtag.get(),likecount.get()))
Comments_with_hash.grid(padx=5,pady=5)
```

**And here is the photo of bot**
https://prnt.sc/21k1nsr.png

**Expected comments i want**

```
Nice and then Amazing and then amazing and nice basically in random
```

**EDITED**
Not able to randomize the sleep time
basically what i want to do it user type 2 numbers like 1,5 to randomize the time between each operation.
**Bot Image :https://prnt.sc/21nj6xm**
**codes i am using**

```
time.sleep(randint(int(delay)))
```

**Error**

```
    time.sleep(randint(int((delay))))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,5'
```

Comment: what is `comment_custom` ? If it is string then using `comment_custom[value]` you get single char from string. And this can be your problem. It should be list of strings. BTW: shorter `random.choice(list_of_strings)`. IF you have string with commas then you chould use `text.split(",")` to create list with strings and then you can  use random string from this list.

Comment: it seems you use string `"1, 5"` but you have to use two integers `randint(1, 5)` or you have to split text `"1,5"` into two strings `values = delay.split(",")` and later convert every value separatelly `randint( int(values[0]), int(values[1]) )`

Comment: i tried your code , this is what i added to my code where i wanted to add sleep
----->   values = delay.split(",") 
randint( int(values[0]), int(values[1]) )    <----

and in delay box i add 5,2 then i get this error
"ValueError: empty range for randrange() (5, 3, -2)"

Comment: error showss `randrange() (5, 3, -2)` but it has to be `randrange( 5, 3, -2 )`. It seems you use it in wrong place. You have wrong `( )`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/21vckq3
have a look, the code is not in wrong place i think

Comment: images show correct code but error can means that you have the same values in both places - try `randrange(5,5)` and you get the same error. Maybe first use `print()` before line which makes problem to see what you have in variables which you use in this line. BTW: I don't understand why you keep `delay` as string - you could use list `delay = [1, 5]` or tuple `delay = (1, 5)`  and then you would paste values without using `int()`  - `randrange(delay[0], delay[1])` or even use `*` to unpack list/tuple `randrange( *delay )`. And of you get `delay` from user then you could convert to int() once.

Comment: Bro can i have your skype or any social media where i can contact you please?

Comment: only email - furas@tlen.pl . You can find it also in my [profile on GitHub](https://github.com/furas). On GitHub you can see code from some of my answers on Stackoveflow: [Python-Examples](https://github.com/furas/python-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run but I guess:

`comment_custom` is single string so using index `comment_custom[index]` you get single char from string.

```py
comment_custom = "hey,amazing,cool"

print( comment_custom[0] ) # char `h`
```

You have to convert it to list of strings/words and then select word from list

```py
comment_custom = "hey,amazing,cool"

words = comment_custom.split(',')

print( words[0] ) # string `hey`
```

---

You could use `random.choice(words)` instead of `words[random.randint(0, len(words)-1)]`

---

So you should do

```py
words = comment_custom.split(',')

comment = random.choice(words)

commet_text.send_keys(comment)
```

Comment: words = comment_custom.split(',')
<This  did the job thanks bro

Comment: I am trying to randomize time.sleep function too , but i am not able to make it work , please check the edited code above .
thanks